# No me sale el url en mi extension de Chrome

Tags: javascript, html5, extensión-google-chrome, manifest

Ando realizando una extension de Chrome y necesito el url de la página que estoy visitando por ejemplo:
Abro google.com, le doy click al icono de mi extension pero en vez de que me salga google.com, me sale el popup.html mi codigo de javascript es este

```
var URLactual = window.location.href;
alert(URLactual);
```

Y mi código del manifest es este:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Prueba de extension",
   "description": "Primer intento de extension",
   "version": "1.0",
   "icons":
   {
    "16": "16.png",
    "48": "48.png",
    "128": "128.png"

   },
   
   "background":{
      "scripts":["background.js"]
   },

   "browser_action":{
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "El link es:"
   },

   "permissions":[
     
      "proxy",
      "vpnProvider",
      "webRequest",
      "cookies"
   ]
}
```

y este es el codigo del background

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,(file:"link.js"})

})
    //chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function())
    <script>  var currentPageUrlIs = "";
if (typeof this.href != "undefined") {
       currentPageUrlIs = this.href.toString().toLowerCase(); 
}else{ 
       currentPageUrlIs = document.location.toString().toLowerCase();
} </script>
```

Muchas gracias por leerme, si me podrian orientar